# System.out.println() of Stream#reduce() unexpectedly prints "Optional[]" around result

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, stdout

I started to learn Lambda expressions of Java 8, and wrote below program to get sum of all numbers in the list:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> number = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

        System.out.println(number.stream().reduce((c,e) -> {
            return c + e;
        }));
    }
}
```

I was expecting the output to be:

> 15

but I got:

> Optional[15]

Java version: *1.8.0_45*

- Please explain what does *Optional[]* means in the output?
- Does it has any significance in Java 8?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html

Comment: Note that you could do `int sum = number.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).sum();`

Comment: @AlexisC. what would be the advantage of using this line of code over the one I used above. thanks.

Comment: No need for unboxing/boxing each time a sum is done.

Answer (score 4):

From the [Java Docs for Stream#reduce()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-), we see that the reduce operation returns an `Optional<T>`. An [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) simply wraps a value if there is a value present, otherwise is "empty".

Important operations on `Optional` include [Optional#isPresent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#isPresent--), which lets you know if there is something in the Optional or not, [Optional#get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#get--), which returns the `T` wrapped in the Optional and throws an exception if called on Empty, and [Optional#orElse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) which returns the `T` wrapped in the Optional if present, or the returns the default value provided if called on Empty.

For your case, the rationale behind `reduce()` returning an `Optional<Integer>` is that the list you're trying to reduce may be empty. In that case, the `Integer` that should be returned is not well defined. For your specific intention `0` would be acceptable (As the sum of the elements in an empty list is `0`), thus you can get the sum as follows:

```
int sum = number.stream().reduce((c,e) -> c + e).orElse(0);
```

That way, even if the list is empty, you will still get a result that defines the sum of the list.

Answer (score 3):

[`reduce(BinaryOperator<T> accumulator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-):

> Returns an `Optional` describing the result of the reduction

[`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html):

> A container object which may or may not contain a non-null value. If a value is present, `isPresent()` will return `true` and `get()` will return the value.

The reason `reduce()` returns an `Optional`, is because the stream might be empty, in which case there would be nothing to reduce, aka no value, and an [`Optional.empty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#empty--) would be returned.

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid Optional in the return you can call to this other method https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator- Just add the identity: "0" before adding the lambda expression. Note that now there is only a **0** as a fist parameter to the reduce call.

```
 System.out.println(number.stream().reduce(0,(c,e) -> {
            return c + e;
        }));
```

returns just

```
15
```

Answer (score 0):

From [java.lang.Object.Optional](http://download.java.net/lambda/b86/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html):

> A container object which may or may not contain a non-null value. If a value is present, isPresent() will return true and get() will return the value.

`Optional` offers two different primary methods for retrieving its value.

[`public T get()`](http://download.java.net/lambda/b86/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#get()) simply returns the value enclosed in the `Optional`, but throws a `NoSuchElementException` if the `Optional` does not wrap a value.

[`orElse(T other)`](http://download.java.net/lambda/b86/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse(T)) returns the value enclosed in the Optional or `other` if the `Optional` does not enclose a value.

EDIT (thanks [@Brian Goetz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3553087/brian-goetz)): 
Generally, `orElse()` is a better choice since `get()` returns a `NoSuchElementException` if the `Optional` contains a null value. True, in this case you will always recieve a value in `Optional` but it's still good practice to primarily use `orElse()`.

So, in your case, you would change

```
System.out.println(number.stream().reduce((c,e) -> {
        return c + e;
}));
```

to:

```
System.out.println(number.stream().reduce((c,e) -> {
        return c + e;
}).orElse(0));
```

which will return the desired value of `15`.

And as [@Brian Goetz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3553087/brian-goetz) said in the comments, if you really wanted to make it succinct you could use `Integer::sum` and a method reference:

```
System.out.println(number.stream.reduce(Integer::sum).orElse(0))
```

which is equivalent to using the longer lambda.

Comment: Also can use Integer::sum instead of the lambda.  (Also also, if you prefer a lambda, you don't need to use a statement lambda, you can use an expression lambda, dropping the braces and "return".)

Answer (score 0):

Got it, thanks @Mshnik and @TimoSta. According to source code of Optional<> which overrides `toString` method

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return value != null
        ? String.format("Optional[%s]", value)
        : "Optional.empty";
}
```

Above code adds that `Optional[]` in my output stream.