# How to return an Optional of sum of even values through stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a stream of random numbers and I need to return an Optional of a sum of even numbers.

Consequently, I have at first to filter appropriate values, then to check if they exist. If not return Optional.empty if yes then sum up and return an Optional with a value.

As I see sum(); findAny(); count(); are terminal operations.
How should I deal with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `reduce()`:

```
randomStream.filter(...).reduce(Integer::sum)
```

This will return an empty optional if there are no elements.

Alternatively, if all the values are positive, you can just check if the result is 0:

```
Optional.of(sum).filter(x -> x > 0)
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain how should I figure out it by myself? I don't want to clog up Stackoverflow with questions about Stream API

Comment: Hmm, good question. It'll definitely help to familiarize yourself with the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) and generally read up on streams. It would also help do some more research; for example, searching "java stream optional sum" might bring you to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35384145/1553851). But if you hit a wall, it's fine to ask here.

Comment: Sorry, can I ask you one more question? reduce() method is abstract and it is defined to return Optional<T> but Integer.sum() returns int. How does it become Optional?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Never mind. Thank you. I'll make an effort to read the links provided by you

Comment: *This will return an optional if there are no elements*: not entirely true, it will always return an optional, but an empty one if there are no elements

Comment: Apparently, you are using the term “positive” in the sense of “more than zero”. I’d not suggest a solution depending on such a subtle constraint. And it doesn’t add any advantage over `.reduce(Integer::sum)`…

Comment: @Holger Also, it might overflow.

Comment: Great use case for `reduce(Math::addExact)`…

Comment: @Holger I actually very much like that you can also the same thing with `StrictMath` - at least the name is obvious...